# If I publish a pre-print, will it make trouble to submit in a journal?

Tags: publications

A certain journal says very explicitly in their submission guideline that -

> "This manuscript has not been published/submitted for publication elsewhere including in local languages or conferences".

If the manuscript has been published as preprint; will this journal consider the article for processing?

Additional question: How common or how rare is the practice for a journal to forbid an article if it has a preprint version published somewhere else?

Comment: You can ask the journal to clarify if they aren't clear about preprints; publication practices with respect to preprints vary widely by field and are always changing.

Comment: Thank you for searching the duplicate. it answers my question. I have been searching this all over internet and getting ambiguous search results.

Comment: Probably why you get ambiguous results is because it differs by journal. Definitely worth asking, it takes little effort for the journal to reply "yes we allow preprints" or "no we do not".